# String cut doesn't work perfectly

Tags: php, string

Currently I use this script:

```
$tstring = strip_tags($nstitle);
if (strlen($tstring) > 65) {

    // truncate string
    $stringCut = substr($tstring, 0, 65);

    // make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
    $tstring = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' ')).
               '.....<a href="">read more</a>'; 
}
```

Sometimes this doesn't work properly if I type two lines and use this for cut string. But it gives different results, like, for instance, getting output where every line is a different length. I want same length of all lines if all same or not.

Answer (score 1):

you can't make every input the same length (65) unless you add padding. since you are essentially chopping off everything after the last space, that last space might occur at a different position in a string. also, if there's no space, you might not get the expected result. so 1. check, and 2. pad.

```
    // truncate string
    $stringCut = substr($tstring, 0, 65);
    //make sure it can find a space
    if (strrpos($stringCut, ' ') > 0) {
        $stringCut = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' '));
    }
    //then pad the string so its always 65 characters long
    while (strlen($stringCut) < 65) {
        $stringCut.="*";
    }

// make sure it ends in a word so assassinate doesn't become ass...
$tstring = $stringCut . '.....<a href="">read more</a>';
```

Comment: @setn dear i get out put with  this symbol * why?

Comment: i like to display output like all strings equal. like i saw in fb group list all group which have long name. but all groups name cut equals.:- )

Comment: Maybe replace the * with whitespace. What fb group are you refering to? Provide a link.

Comment: no work dear still same problem..
look if i type 10 lines and every lines have diffrent words and diffrent space and some have many space after 1 sentence. but whe i appy string cut code i wanted to display result all lines cut equals . and al lines width equal.
 bcoz if width not equal then my text fields not like good its break my design which i work currenlty:- ) hope u understand my problem

Comment: your not providing enough information. it sounds like you need to look at a block of text and process it line by line but your code as written will only process one line.

Comment: actualy i have multiples box which contain texts and box width is fixed when i use string cutter php script its make some boxes text lines equal and its make some larger and my boxes looks bad bcoz i have multiple boxes thats y need text fields equal and if text more then as i set value then display also see more link.